# Is there a way to create break points en mass for an entire block of code with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to select a large consecutive body of code in the Chrome console and add breakpoints to all lines en mass without adding them one-by-one. I want to know if this is possible and if so how.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to breakpoint the first line and then press "step over"? This is how it's normally done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F10` lets you step through your code one step at a time if you're already hit a breakpoint!

There are four ways to end up at a breakpoint:

- Set one in your code (at the top of the sequence you want to debug, then you can Step Over)
- Press the "Pause" button in the Chrome developer tools
- Put the statement `debugger;` on the line you want to break on in your source code (often convenient!)
- Turn on "Pause on exceptions" (fourth button on the bottom, looks like a pause button in a circle) which toggles between "don't pause", "pause on all exceptions", and "pause on unhandled exceptions".

Enjoy!